# Continues updating view with data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am using data binding for setting data to `recyclerview item` and I am using `@BindingAdapter` for custom attrinbutes.
Now i want to update the text of a textview in each second. The textview is displaying a text(time ago) with related to a timestamp, i have created a `@BindingAdapter` function by passing the timestamp, which works perfectly for setting the text single time, but i want to update it in each second.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:timeago="@{order.DateStamp}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvOrderId"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Just now" />
```

Following is my binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("timeago")
    public static void setTimeAgo(TextView view, long time) {
        view.setText(getTimeAgo(time));
    }
```

[this is my layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M2gn.png)

Comment: where are you calling this function setTimeAgo() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EchoBind class, BindingAdapter for this.

The binding should be in two way from XML to model/adapter or model/adapter to XML.

To get detailed documentation refer these [link1](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761)  & [link2](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/two-way-data-binding-on-android-observing-your-view-with-xml/).